# Move-Item Powershell move files/folders from folder to a new subfolder while preserving folder structure

Tags: powershell, copy

Hi I want to move items from my current folder `./` to a new subfolder `./new` such that I'm preserving the folder structure for the items I am moving.

I tried:

```
$source = './'
$dest = './new'

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $newPath = $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source),$dest
    Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
}
```

However, this gives me errors such as:

> Cannot find path 'C:\Users\me\testpo\sub' because it does not exist.

`testpo` is the current directory that contains the subfolder `week2` that contains the subfolder `sub`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i get the error `destination cannot be a sub directory of the source`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i’m trying the command Get-ChildItem -Path ./ -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination ./new ——> but still same error with MoveItem so i might need to change the logic

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks that’ll be useful. Yeah seems more hacky than i thought

Comment: So, one thing to note, you want to move a parent folder to a child of that parent, which is simply not possible, you can however move all files and folder of that parent into the child subfolder. If thats what you want then you can do it like this: `Move-Item $source\* $dest -Exclude $dest -Force`

Comment: Glad it worked, you could self answer showing the code that solved your problem. It might help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

I used this command that Santiago suggested and it worked: `Move-Item $source\* $dest -Exclude $dest -Force`